# Are these r/w speeds OK for raid 0 nvme?

Tags: raid, nvme

I have a raid 0 setup of nvme. I think they should read/write much faster. Can you kindly check if this is ok? Maybe I have just bought slow nvmes

CPU intel 11700
NVME 2x ADATA XPG GAMMIX S50 Lite 1 TB (PCIE4, random iops around 300k)
RAM 32G

iostat shows util almost always in red

```
Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
md127         2123,89 134918,47     0,00   0,00    8,69    63,52 2234,84 141061,55     0,00   0,00   12,98    63,12    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00   47,45  83,84
nvme0n1        655,09  67459,21   639,03  49,38    6,41   102,98 1597,24  70529,02   436,65  21,47    5,36    44,16    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00   12,77  75,03
nvme1n1        654,64  67459,24   638,50  49,38    6,94   103,05 1602,74  70532,53   431,25  21,20    4,76    44,01    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00   12,18  76,07
```

also have like 30% iowait all the time

Is this normal? Maybe I have missed something during raid0 creation or in bios. Btw I have accidentally removed MBR partition on one of the nvme but I think this should not matter

Comment: RAID 0 using SSDs is really not worth it. The read speed of SSDs are insanely faster than HDDs.  RAID 0 could improve the performance of HDD disks via striping but the typical SSD is already so fast that the use of RAID 0 can be negligible. Since you have even faster SSDs, you might even cause the performance to be *worse* than one SSD by itself to accommodate to *overhead* consumed by this RAID configuration.  You also increase your chances of drive failure as you are writing more than you would without RAID

Comment: hi @Nmath do you think the raid0 would slow them down this much? Also I noticed that sudo hdparm -I /dev/nvme1 returns:
/dev/nvme1:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device